# How is the `--description` option in Fish used?

Tags: fish

I've noticed the `--description` option as a part of function declarations in Fish shell syntax.

For example, `/usr/share/fish/functions/abbr.fish`:

```
function abbr --description "Manage abbreviations"
    …
end
```

However, I've never seen it used. None of the following commands do what I'm trying to accomplish, which is view the description of any given function (provided that it's defined):

```
> abbr --description
abbr: Unknown option “--description”
/usr/share/fish/functions/abbr.fish (line 6): 
    argparse -n abbr $options -- $argv
    ^
in function 'abbr' with arguments '--description'
> help --description
help: Unknown option “--description”
/usr/share/fish/functions/help.fish (line 3): 
    argparse -n help --max-args=1 $options -- $argv
    ^
in function 'help' with arguments '--description'
> help description # opens file:///usr/share/doc/fish/index.html in a browser (same functionality as `help`)
> help abbr # opens file:///usr/share/doc/fish/cmds/abbr.html in a browser (only works for built-in functions)
```

I haven't seen anything about this option in the documentation. If it's there, please point me to it.

Comment: AS you can probably guess, the option just allows to provide a description. It's odd that you received an error for that definition, it works for version 3.1.2, what version of fish are you running?

Comment: I am running 3.1.2, also. Should I post *~/.config/fish/config.fish* as well? I don't think there's anything in there that would break it.

Comment: Oh i see your confusion. You are trying to call the abbr function with the `description` option. The option is more of a really simple "docstring" of sorts for the developer, it is not designed to be seen by the end user. Its an option on the `function` command, it is not adding one to the function being made

Comment: So if it's not to be viewed, why pass it to `function` at all? Is it effectively a special comment?

Comment: Basically, its there for the developer. For example, the function `function fish_git_prompt --description "Prompt function for Git"`, it has a very brief description of the function's purpose. It does seem overly verbose and repetitive, unless its resolving an ambiguous function name

Comment: @puffin, please summarize your comments and post as an answer. Your responses were the most detailed and useful, and I would like to mark them as accepted.

Comment: Glad to help, and thanks for accepting the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call the `abbr` function with the `--description` option. The option is more of a really simple "docstring" of sorts for the developer, it is not designed to be seen by the end user. Its an option on the `function` command, it is not adding any help strings or other functionality to the function being defined.

Take the fish function `fish_git_prompt` defined in `/usr/share/fish/functions/fish_git_prompt.fish`. Its full definition is `function fish_git_prompt --description "Prompt function for Git"`, and the description provides a very brief explanation of the purpose. The descriptions are pretty repetitive and overly verbose, but would be more useful for short function names which may be ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

The `--description` option is to add a [docstring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring) for your function definition.

Docstrings help with inspecting other developers codes. It is also useful for users of your functions and is in fact designed to be seen by the user, in several places.

- In <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion menus
- In the output of `type` for a function
- In the output of `functions -vD` *funcname* ( *v* erbose *D* etails)

Examples, using this simple function definition:

```
mjl@jazz ~> function ... -d 'Go up two directory levels.'
                ../../
            end
```

#### Hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

This is the *most* useful purpose of `--description`|`-d`.  After typing <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>, this is how Fish shows the completions (it added the third `.`):

```
mjl@jazz ~> ...
..  ...  (Go up two directory levels.)  ../  (Directory, 160B)
```

The description appears, so that the user can tell at a glance what the meaning of `...` *is*.

#### Listing the function:

```
mjl@jazz ~> type ...
... is a function with definition
function ... --description 'Go up two directory levels.'
../../
end
```

#### Showing the function's details:

```
mjl@jazz ~> functions -vD ...
stdin
n/a
0
scope-shadowing
Go up two directory levels.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--description` option is to provide a description of the defined function, of course the abbr command doesn't have a description option, because it belongs to `function` command (and abbr doesn't have such option)

See fish docs:

- https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/function.html#description
- https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/abbr.html#options

Comment: I see the option listed, but I don't see how it is intended to be used. Also, I didn't redefine `abbr`; I just copied from the built-in directory.